# MainActivity Get destroyed when coming from notfication

Tags: android

When I get notification my app navigate user to the detail screen of the app, this is the code that will open DetailActivity on notification tap.

```
 Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            nextIntent.putExtra(FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);
            nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            TaskStackBuilder taskStack = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            taskStack.addNextIntent(nextIntent);


            PendingIntent pendingIntent = taskStack.getPendingIntent(getNotificaitonId(userContact.getPhone()),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

If user left the app by pressing the home button MainActivity is still there and when user come to DetailActivity from notificatioin, I observer MainActivity got destroyed.

How can avoid destroying the of MainActivity if it's still there ???

Also to allow user to go back to MainActivity when coming from DetailActivity this is what I'm doing in `OnBackPressed()`

```
 if( isComingFromNotificationScreen ) {
      Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
      if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent) || isTaskRoot()) {
          TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                  .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                  .startActivities();
      } else {
          NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
      }
  }
  else
  {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
```

Comment: What you mean by destoryed?. Crashed?. If yes please include the  stacktrace.

Comment: not crashed it gets destroyed onDestroyed() gets called

Comment: Which mean super.onBackPressed() is called. isComingFromNotificationScreen is false in that case.

Comment: isComingFromNotifications is true when comiing from notification, which open DetailActivity and also called the onDestroy() on MainActvity.